# Парсинг Json в React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

у меня в пост ответе есть   JSON [image: res.body]

Могу ли я спарсить этот json в React? Каким образом можно получить доступ к этому массиву в React?

Comment: Также как и не в React, через JSON.parse()

Comment: а как мне в  JSON.parse() засунуть пост ответ?

Comment: Ну что значит как? Как первый аргумент метода JSON.parse.

Answer (score 2):

например, через rest библиотеку axios:

```
...
axios.get('http://some url').then(response => this.setState({data: response.data);

...
console.log(this.state.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Или через Fetch API и async/await

```js
async componentDidMount() {
  const res = await fetch("api url");
  const data = await res.json();
  this.setState({data: data})
}
```